# Port is open and listening but is denying connections

Tags: apache-2.4, port, fedora, curl

Port is open and listening but is denying connections.

When trying to CURL in terminal

```
curl --data-binary '{"id":"curltext","method":"addrequest","params":{"amount":"3.14","memo":"test"}}' http://user:pass@127.0.0.1:7777
```

Error Message

```
curl: (7) Failed to connect to 127.0.0.1 port 7777: Connection refused
```

Below are my netstats. Port is open and listening.

```
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State      
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:7777          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN     
tcp6       0      0 :::80                   :::*                    LISTEN
```

The command

```
curl -v 127.0.0.1 7777
```

Returns:

```
Rebuilt URL to: 127.0.0.1/
*   Trying 127.0.0.1...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to 127.0.0.1 (127.0.0.1) port 80 (#0)
> GET / HTTP/1.1
> Host: 127.0.0.1
> User-Agent: curl/7.55.1
> Accept: */*
> 
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Date: Wed, 04 Apr 2018 18:22:14 GMT
< Server: Apache/2.4.29 (Fedora)
< X-Powered-By: PHP/7.1.15
< Transfer-Encoding: chunked
< Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
< 

/*index.php code*/

* Connection #0 to host 127.0.0.1 left intact
* Rebuilt URL to: 7777/
*   Trying 0.0.30.97...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Immediate connect fail for 0.0.30.97: Invalid argument
* Closing connection 1
curl: (7) Couldn't connect to server
```

`linux Fedora 27` `Apache 2.4` `Electrum 3.1.2`

Comment: Is your firewall on?

Comment: Possible. IP tables not installed. systemctl disable firewalld returns:
Failed to disable unit: Unit file firewalld.service does not exist.

Comment: You cannot use `curl` with the latter invocation method to an HTTP request to `127.0.0.1` port `7777`. As you can see from the output, it tries to connect first to `127.0.0.1` port `80` and then to `0.0.30.97`, which is an IP address converted from `7777`. Now, in order to answer the actual question, you need to provide information what exactly is running at port `7777`. Also, the first `curl` command verbose (`-v`) output is useful.